# hspec test arguments work on command line but not from .hspec file

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hspec

I am following the [hspec documentation](http://hspec.github.io/options.html) on passing options to Hspec. Specifying my option works as expected when passed from the command line, but not when passed from the `.hspec` file or any of the other listed methods.

One of the tests in my test suite matches the filter "post_returns_200". I can run this test alone without running the rest of the suite via the command

```
stack test --test-arguments=--match="post_returns_200"
```

The linked hspec documentation shows that I should be able to specify this filter not only from the command line, but also: from an `.hspec` file, from within `ghci`, or from an environment variable. When I follow the documentation to specify my filter by one of those other methods, however, I get an "unrecognized option" error. For instance, when I specify the option in the `.hspec` file via

```
$ echo --match="post_returns_200">>.hspec
```

then running `stack test` returns the following

```
$ stack test
azara-api-0.1.0.0: test (suite: azara-test)

azara-test: unrecognized option `--match="post_returns_200"' in config file /home/matthew/backup/azara_work/platform/api/.hspec

Test suite failure for package azara-api-0.1.0.0
    azara-test:  exited with: ExitFailure 1
Logs printed to console
```

When I attempt to specify the option via an environment variable or from within ghci, I get a similar error. I have tried many variations on how to specify the command, e.g. with or without quotes, with and without "`--test-arguments=`", but I am totally stumped at this point. Any suggestions on why the option works properly when specified via command line but is unrecognized by the other methods?

Comment: Have you tried simply `$ echo --match=post_returns_200>.hspec`? (using `>` to overwrite the file instead of appending to it, since otherwise it will still contain the `--match="post_returns_200"` line.)

Comment: @M.Aroosi Yes, tried that and get same error. So same error with `.hspec` file containing just the single line `--match=post_returns_200`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason I ignore, hspec recognizes a different set of options in the command line and in config files.

As of now, explicit command line arguments (via `--test-arguments` when using stack) is the only way to pass `--match` to hspec.

---

From the source code of 2.4.4 (which has changed a lot on the current active branch, but it still doesn't allow what you want either):

- [Command line options](https://github.com/hspec/hspec/blob/2.4.4/hspec-core/src/Test/Hspec/Core/Options.hs#L242) are parsed with [`recognizedOptions`](https://github.com/hspec/hspec/blob/2.4.4/hspec-core/src/Test/Hspec/Core/Options.hs#L233), containing both [`commandLineOptions`](https://github.com/hspec/hspec/blob/2.4.4/hspec-core/src/Test/Hspec/Core/Options.hs#L148) (which includes `--match`) and [`configFileOptions`](https://github.com/hspec/hspec/blob/2.4.4/hspec-core/src/Test/Hspec/Core/Options.hs#L158).
- [Config file options](https://github.com/hspec/hspec/blob/2.4.4/hspec-core/src/Test/Hspec/Core/Options.hs#L250), via [`parseOtherOptions`](https://github.com/hspec/hspec/blob/2.4.4/hspec-core/src/Test/Hspec/Core/Options.hs#L258), use only `configFileOptions`, which don't include `--match`.